# SqlBulkCopy Max Number of Columns

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with a table that has 575 columns in it. I have a CSV file that matches the table.

When I use `SqlBulkCopy` (.NET 4), only the first 256 columns get populated. The rest get nulls inserted into them. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Thanks,
ts3

Comment: I've tried with a table with 400 odd columns (all integers) and the bulk insert works fine - all 400 columns are populated

Comment: how are you loading the CSV? what library, and in to what data structure? Could there be a limitation there somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to guess that your primary key column is autoincrementing from zero and it is of type tinyint. If so then you should change your primary key on that column to be an integer or something that can hold more values.

Comment: Paul, I don't understand your answer? The primary key type would affect the number of rows allowed, not the number of columns. What am I missing?